# How to hide or remove scrolling sidebars while using overflow in css?

Tags: css

I have a burger class and I want to use `overflow` property to scroll. But when I use it this is how it looks:
[image]

I want to have that scrolling effect, but at the same time, I don't want those scroll bars to appear sidewise:
[image]

Here is my css class:

```
.Burger
{
    width: 100%;
    margin: auto;
    height: 250px;
    text-align: center;
    overflow: scroll;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 1.2rem;
}
```

Does anyone know what else can I add in these properties to hide that side scrolling bars. I want the affect to be present but not the bars, like this:

[image]

Comment: Maybe set the overflow to auto instead of scroll.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To hide your scrollbars but keep scrolling
Add this to your code

```
/* Hide scrollbar for Chrome, Safari and Opera */
.Burger::-webkit-scrollbar {
  display: none;
}

/* Hide scrollbar for IE, Edge and Firefox */
.Burger {
  overflow-y: scroll; /* Add the ability to scroll */
  -ms-overflow-style: none;  /* IE and Edge */
  scrollbar-width: none;  /* Firefox */
}
```

also see this [W3Schools](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_hide_scrollbars.asp)

and the Browser compatibility for [::-webkit-scrollbar](https://caniuse.com/?search=%3A-webkit-scrollbar)

Answer (score 1):

```
.burger{
  overflow: scroll; /* Add the ability to scroll */
  -ms-overflow-style: none;  /* IE and Edge */
  scrollbar-width: none;  /* Firefox */

}

/* Hide scrollbar */
.burger::-webkit-scrollbar {
    display: none;
}
```

Try This I Guess this helps if it's what you're looking for

[Also see at W3Schools](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_css_hide_scrollbar_keep_func)